# Why is there space between tabs?

Tags: javascript, html, css, content-management-system

New to HTML/CSS coding. Every time I plug this code into the CMS I am using, there are white spaces in between the tabs. I have plugged the code into random online editors which does not show the white spaces in between. What am I doing wrong?

(It's forcing me to write more details). The CMS I am using was developed by an independent, small company so there are some limitations to the editing capabilities. Not sure if that has anything to do with it.

I want: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFxmm.png)

I have (you can ignore the change in titles): [2]

```css
<style>
  body {
    background: #fff;
    font-family: 'Arial';
}
.mytabs {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: 50px auto;
    padding: 0px;
}
.mytabs input[type="radio"] {
    display: none;
    float: left;
    
}
.mytabs label {
    padding: 25px;
    background: #612141;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #fff;
}

.mytabs .tab {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    background: #fff;
    order: 1;
    display: none;
    border: solid;
    border: 3px solid #a6192e;
}
.mytabs .tab h2 {
    font-size: 2em;
}

.mytabs input[type='radio']:checked + label + .tab {
    display: block;
}

.mytabs input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
    background: #c1a91e;
}

</style>
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="mytabs">
    <input type="radio" id="tabbananas" name="mytabs" checked="checked">
    <label for="tabbananas">Bananas</label>
    <div class="tab">
    </div>

    <input type="radio" id="tabapples" name="mytabs">
    <label for="tabapples">Apples</label>
    <div class="tab">
    </div>

    <input type="radio" id="taboranges" name="mytabs">
    <label for="taboranges">Oranges</label>
    <div class="tab">


<p>&nbsp;</p>
</div>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don’t think we can fully debug this as we don’t have access to the version within the CMS but what do you see when you use your browser dev tools inspect facility on one of those tabs? Something is setting something in the CSS.

Answer (score 1):

First of all I couldn't reproduce the issue because it has no whitespace between tabs for me.
Anyway, I guess this whitespace will be removed if you set labels `margin` to `0`.

```
.mytabs>label {
    margin: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This helped under the CMS I am using.